# JsTree with static nodes and dynamic loading nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I have a jsTree that dynamically loads it's nodes, when they are getting expanded. This is the init method of the tree.

```
function initializeTree(treeSelector, fnId,callback) {
treeSelector.jstree({
plugins: ["types", "wholerow"],
core: {
    animation: false,
    multiple: false,
    themes: {
    dots: false
    },
    data: {
           url: userlogicServlet,
           data: function (node) {
           return {cmd: 'getTreeNode', oid: node.id, fnId: fnId};
           }
          }
     }
}).on("ready.jstree", function () {
    callback(treeSelector);
});

}
```

Additionally I want to add two static nodes to the root of the tree. As they can vary, I want to give the function, that adds the static nodes as callback. The callback gets executed as soon as the tree fires "ready". Means the first level of data is loaded (I'm in the believe this is the case when the "ready" event gets fired).

This is one of the possible callback methods, that should add a new node on top of the tree.

```
 _addVariableToTree: function (tree) {
var variableNode = {"id": "addVariableNode", "text": "Add Variable", "type": "Add"};
tree.jstree().create_node( '#', variableNode, "first");
}
```

Following the jstree doc, this should work. As you can assume it doesn't.

The dynamic data gets loaded, the callback gets executed, but the node "Add Variable" is not getting added. As well, there is no exception occurring.

does anyone have an idea or assumption, what could be wrong in here?

**UPDATE:**

I just had a little try with this fiddler http://jsfiddle.net/DGAF4/1200/
which seems to work.

Could it be, that in my case, I indeed add the static node before the first dynamic data is loaded and it gets swept away again as soon the first level is received?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With that fiddler, I found my mistake.

I did not have the `check_callback : true` option set for the tree.
with that it works as expected.